# iOS. How to draw complex images on a UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, insets

I need to make something like this (rectangles mean various pictures):

[image]

I know that it is possible to do this by making one image from two and assigning it to a UIButton. But is there another way to do it by using insets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "button pressed" highlighted state for both images you could

- Make it one image and one button
- Make two buttons and assign images and implement a method (add to both buttons as target for UIControlEventAllEvents) that sets `button1.highlighted` & `button2.highlighted = ((UIButton*)sender).highlighted`